# First and Last Time of Day

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to run a query to sort out records for the first time an event occurs during the day, and the last time an event happens during the day, and run the report to include a week of recorded history on the system. This is in a SQL2005 database, but I haven't found anything to help me narrow things down to just a first occurrance and a last occurance.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Test data in table @T
declare @T table(id int, dt datetime)
insert into @T values (1, '2011-01-01T10:00:00')
insert into @T values (2, '2011-01-01T11:00:00')
insert into @T values (3, '2011-01-01T12:00:00')
insert into @T values (4, '2011-01-02T20:00:00')
insert into @T values (5, '2011-01-02T21:00:00')
insert into @T values (6, '2011-01-02T22:00:00')

-- First day of interval to query
declare @FromDate datetime = '2011-01-01'
-- Add 7 days to get @ToDate
declare @ToDate datetime = dateadd(d, 7, @FromDate)

;with cte as 
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by datediff(d, T.dt, 0) order by T.dt) as rnMin,
    row_number() over(partition by datediff(d, T.dt, 0) order by T.dt desc) as rnMax
  from @T as T
  where T.dt >= @FromDate and T.dt < @ToDate
)
select C.id, C.dt
from cte as C
where C.rnMax = 1 or C.rnMin = 1
order by C.dt
```